# Is there a kindle with a light up screen but NOT a touchscreen?

Tags: kindle

I currently have a 3rd gen Kindle with physical buttons.  I love the physical buttons, but would also like to have a screen that lights up.  I've browsed the list of kindles [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Kindle) and didn't seem to find any that weren't touch screens but also light up.

I'm just looking for an ebook reader that has:
* Physical buttons (no touchscreen, don't like the idea of accidental clicks)
* Lights up
* Part of the Amazon ecosystem.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

**No**
All the  currently available Kindles have a touchscreen.
One solution would be to buy an old [kindle lighted cover](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003DZ165W)

Answer (score 1):

The current answer is technically no.

**BUT**

You can use a [Kindle Oasis](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B06XDK92KS/ref=ods_cc_eink_cog#tech) (from 2017) nearly all by buttons.  Some search screens are scrollable only by touch but you rarely need to use them and selecting a choice e.g. a book from the library requires touch. Paging through a book can be done by button.

Answer (score -1):

No, Sorry, the light up screen kindle are all touch screens

Comment: Do you have a reference to support this? While I suspect it is probably true, a reference supported answer is less likely to be down voted or deleted.

Answer (score -1):

buy kindle cover with lights. It takes power from the kindle so you don't need to charge them separately

Comment: How does that apply to buttons or touch screen

Comment: @mmmmmm I'd say this answer is suggesting using any kindle that has physical buttons and use a cover with lights as an alternative to a screen that *Lights up*.